# Javascript Show/Hide Div's not working. Trying to simulate VirginMedia Contact Us page (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Attempting to emulate Contact Us page which is split into three equally sized divs. Attempted to use JS to set click set to reveal corresponding div and to hide any div which is open. For some reason the code is not working. Any help is appreciated. I will remove my css as it is just the HTML/JS which is not working.

I have tried writing individual functions for each of the list items and it did not close the previous (open) div upon clicking a different div.
 Here goes:

```js
var showDivs = function(){

    //get array of all columns in the list
    var columns = document.getElementsByClassName('column');

    //get length of array
    var columnsLength = columns.length;

    //run a for loop through all the columns to apply the click function
    for(var a=0;a<columnsLength;a++){

      //get the element
      var el = columns[a];

      //set the on click
      el.onclick = function(e){

        //get the targeted element
        var _this = e.currentTarget;

        //get element ID
        var _thisId = _this.getAttribute("id");

        //slice ID to get number
        var _thisIdIndex = _thisId.slice(7);

        //get related content
        var _thisContent = document.getElementById("content-"+_thisIdIndex);

        //check to see if content is displaying already
        if(_thisContent.style.display === "block"){

          //yes - so hide it
          _thisContent.style.display = "none";
        }else{
          //no so lets hide all others and show it
          //get array of content
          var contents = document.getElementsByClassName('content');

          //get length of array
          var contentsLength = contents.length;

          //run a for loop through all content to apply hide or show
          for(var b=0;b<contentsLength;b++){

            //does the content ID NOT equal the ID of the related column index
            if(contents[b].getAttribute("id") !== "content-"+_thisIdIndex){

              //correct - hide this content
              contents[b].style.display = "none";
            }else{
              //nope - this is the content to show!
              contents[b].style.display = "block";
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  showDivs();
```

```css
.container{width:100%;}
.content{display: none;}
.column{width:33%;float:left;}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
    <!--Table Left Column - Original Problem-->

        <div class="firstcolumn">
            <ul class="formatfix">
                <li class="title"><p style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">1. Choose a topic</p></li>
                <li id="column-ONE" class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 1</a></li>
                <li id="column-TWO" class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 2</a></li>
                <li id="column-THREE" class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 3</a></li>
                <li id="column-FOUR" class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 4</a></li>
                <li id="column-FIVE" class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 5</a></li>
                <li id="column-SIX" class="border-top selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Something else</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <!-- Table Middle Column - Option 1 List-->

        <div id="content-ONE" class="column content">
            <ul class="formatfix">
                <li class="border-bottom title"><p style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">2. Tell us more</p></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>List 1 Option 1</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>List 1 Option 2</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>List 1 Option 3</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>List 1 Option 4</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>List 1 Option 5</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>List 1 Option 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <!-- Table Middle Column - Option 2 List-->

        <div id="content-TWO" class="column content">
            <ul class="formatfix">
                <li class="border-bottom title"><p style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">2. Tell us more</p></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 1</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 2</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 3</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 4</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 5</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <!-- Table Middle Column - Option 3 List-->

        <div id="content-THREE" class="column content">
            <ul class="formatfix">
                <li class="border-bottom title"><p style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">2. Tell us more</p></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 1</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 2</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 3</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 4</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 5</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <!-- Table Middle Column - Option 4 List-->

        <div id="content-FOUR" class="column content">
            <ul class="formatfix">
                <li class="border-bottom title"><p style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">2. Tell us more</p></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 1</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 2</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 3</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 4</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 5</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <!-- Table Middle Column - Option 5 List-->

        <div id="content-FIVE" class="column content">
            <ul class="formatfix">
                <li class="border-bottom title"><p style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">2. Tell us more</p></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 1</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 2</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 3</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 4</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 5</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <!--  Something Else Column -->

        <div id="content-SIX" class="column content">
            <ul class="formatfix">
                <li class="border-bottom title"><p style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">2. Tell us more</p></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 1</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 2</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 3</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 4</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 5</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a><i class="fa-tbc"></i>Option 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

As it stands, nothing happens upon click. There may be a problem with the HTML but I am too junior to express what the JS needs to work. Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's because you added your script in the head, try to move it to the bottom of the body (before closing </body>). Thing is your script is evaluated before the body is rendered, and that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Yup, either what @Goran.it said or you could also put the `showDivs();` call inside a "DOMContentLoaded" event listener like this: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", showDivs);`

Comment: Do you want to add click function to the your choose topic list option or not? If yes, you add it to the items that have css columns class but you hide them by adding content css class. There is nothing wrong in your code but I think you add the function to the wrong items.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of errors.
Mainly `columns` start as `undefined` because you look in the view BEFORE the view has loaded.
If you do:

```
setTimeout (() => {            
    showDivs ();
}, 500);
```

Then yes columns will be defined.

But this approach is not correct either. You must put an `onload` tag in the `<body>` and pass it a function. Then in this function the view is going to be loaded, and you can work quietly.

I recommend investigating how to debug in javascript.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.

I have fixed the issue by changing the JS code from "thisTarget" to "target" as I was selecting the div around the list, and also the id was on the list item and not on the link.

Script is also at the bottom of the page...

All working now!